# Sums with multiple lines of limits

Tags: math-mode

How do I do something like this:

[image]

where the `$p\leq x$` and `$p\equiv\pmod{q}$` are on separate lines?

Comment: `\substack{<line_1>\\<line_2>\\...\\<line_n>}` as in `\[  \sum_{\substack{p \leq x\\p \equiv a \mod q}} \]` (needs `\usepackage{amsmath}`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try this:

```
\[
\sum_{\shortstack{$p\leq x$\\ $p\equiv a \mod q $ }}
\]
```

or

```
\[
\sum_{\begin{aligned} & p\leq x \\ & p\equiv a \pmod q \end{aligned}}
\]
```

[image]

Comment: The "correct" answer is `\substack` or `subarray`. Besides, `$$` should never be used in LaTeX.